# Carregar apenas thumbnail de vídeos do Youtube

Tags: php, youtube, iframe

Tenho uma página que em seu layout há 20 vídeos do Youtube, é uma listagem.
Como não quero fazer essa página realmente carregar todos esses vídeos para não compremeter o desempenho do site, pois `iframe` pesa muito. Gostaria de saber se tem como carregar apenas o thumbnail do vídeo, ai quando eu clico abre um colorbox, ou algo do gênero.

Comment: E o carregamemto é dinâmico? Se você quer alguma alternativa seria melhor detalhar mais a pergunta

Comment: @brasofilo o usuário irá incluir os vídeos através de um gerenciador de conteúdo próprio desenvolvido aonde trabalho, ou seja, o carregamento é dinâmico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Através de URL

O [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) tem um URL específico para se recolher as *thumbnails* dos vídeos:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/#.jpg
```

O `#` pode ser 0, 1, 2 ou 3 que correspondem as *thumbnails* que o YouTube gera para o vídeo:

Via número:

```
0 = 480×360 pixeis (Tamanho normal)
1 = 120×90 pixeis  (captura 01)
2 = 120×90 pixeis  (captura 02)
3 = 120×90 pixeis  (captura 03)
```

Via Qualidade:

```
default = 120x90 pixeis    (normal)
mqdefault = 320x180 pixels (qualidade média)
hqdefault = 480x360 pixels (qualidade elevada)
```

Para vídeos HD também temos:

```
sddefault = 640x480 pixels       (normal)
maxresdefault = 1920x1080 pixels (máxima resolução)
```

A utilização é simples:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/wDP2Q11Dc5k/1.jpg
```

ou

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/wDP2Q11Dc5k/default.jpg
```

[image: Thumbnail]

---

## Através da API v2.0

O uso da API é extremamente recomendado pois a recolha de thumbnails a partir do URL não se encontra documentada tornando-a inviável.

Exemplo para utilizar a API para recolher a mesma *thumbnail* em cima apresentada:

#### jQuery e [YouTube API 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)

```js
$.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wDP2Q11Dc5k?v=2&alt=jsonc", function(json){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", json.data.thumbnail.sqDefault).appendTo("body");
});
```

Muitas outras informações são fornecidas com o uso da API:

[image: JSON Retornado pela API]

Comment: Muito obrigado. Será que há algum plugin que faça isso automaticamente?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Quem sabe ;) É uma questão de analisares os [vários existentes](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+plugin+youtube). O primeiro resultado está muito perto daquilo que pretendes: http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

Comment: Show de bola, tá abrindo tipo um colorbox! Só gostaria de saber como fazer ele pegar a imagem automaticamente. Pois no exemplo está manual. Sou meio leigo nisso, se puder ajudar! :)

Meu código está assim `<img class="youtube" id="" src="codigoSYS" />`, o `codigoSYS` ele pega o iframe do meu sistema.

Comment: Se houvesse alguma forma de informar no `id` só o `cyEh0W5d-NQ`(por exemplo)

Comment: A API v2 parece não funcionar mais...

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente as imagens são gravadas no servidor `img.youtube`.

Sabendo disso temos duas soluções:

1. Pegar a imagem da url hardcoded https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id_do_video}/0.jpg
2. Utilizar a API do youtube para recuperar as urls das imagens.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo juntando jQuery para substituir o thumbnail do YouTube pelo iFrame com o vídeo em `autoplay`.

A variável `$yids` é uma coleção de IDs de vídeo e dela puxam-se os thumbnails: `http://img.youtube.com/vi/$video/0.jpg`, e o `iframe` que é injetado via jQuery usando essa mesma ID.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>nth-child demo</title>
  <style>
  ul { list-style-type: none; }
  a.y-img { opacity: .5; }
  a.y-img:hover { opacity: 1; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    <?php
    $yids = array( '5MnhFmFDLj8', 'Bl4Qne-RpcM', '3zzWoWojYQI', 'ep0_0W0qWsc', 'eORqFaf_QzM', 'WdkT4_OJ2WU' );
    foreach( $yids as $video ) {
        // http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php
        printf( 
            '<li class="y-thumbs"><a data-yt="%s" href="javascript:;" class="y-img"><img src="%s" /></a></li>', 
            $video,
            "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$video/0.jpg"
        );
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
<script>
$('a.y-img').on( 'click', function(){
    // Substitui todo o conteúdo do <li> pelo iframe
    $(this).parent().html( '<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('yt') + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pode-se extrair a ID do vídeo a partir da URL do YouTube [usando esta função](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556662/1287812).